Can detect domcontentloaded event while using waituntil:load in playwright?
I'm using playwright with nodejs and working on old code base. In that code, waituntil is set to "domcontentloaded" but I need to change it to "load" because I need to count network requests of fully loaded web page. But if I change to "load" the performance matric of "load" and "domcontentloaded" becomes a bit different. For example- if we use with "domcontentloaded" it took 500ms but with "load" it took 1000ms. Due to that difference I am finding a solution that does not break the old function. What I want to know is can we detect "domcontentloaded" event while running on waituntil:load?
Currently, I am using with waituntil:load but if there is a way I'm going to change it.

"domcontentloaded" is a precursor of all the other load events except "commit". So waiting until "load" also waits for "domcontentloaded". I don't really understand the question though--how are you supposed to wait for those resources to resolve without the script taking more time to complete? Yes, "load" is slower, but if you need to wait, you need to wait. How does using "load" break the old function, exactly, other than taking a bit longer?

Can you share an self contained code example of what you have tried so far and depict exactly what's the problem with reference to that code. Currently the way its presented here is very vague for somebody to undertstand and comment something to provide any useful information.

I would encourage to look at it from 3rd person perspective if somebody asked you this question in exactly this form, what kind of queries and information you would require to understand and help that person and provide the same information here.
